# can't retrieve css properties from popup.js elements more than once

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, popup

I have this strange issue with this jquery-based popup script I found [here](http://docs.toddish.co.uk/popup/).

The issue is : When I try to get the 'imageGallery' background and alert it, it will work only once. If I close the popup (by clicking outside of it) and open it again it won't work.

Do you know how to solve this one? I would like this to work every time I open the popup and not only on the first time it opens.

```js
$('a.popup').popup();

$(".imageGallery").on('click', function() {
    var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
    alert(bg);
});
```

```css
.imageGallery { width: 200px; height: 250px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://docs.toddish.co.uk/css/plugins/popup.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://docs.toddish.co.uk/js/plugins/jquery.popup.min.js"></script>

<div class="imageChoice" style="background-size: 200 250; height: 200; width: 250;"><a href=#gallery class="popup">Open gallery</a>
</div>

<div id="gallery" style="display:none">
  <div class="imageGallery" style="background-image:url('http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/apple_topic.png?w=600'); background-size: 200 250; height: 200; width: 250;"></div>

  <div class="imageGallery" style="background-image:url('http://images.clipartpanda.com/educational-clipart-M9TpyejiE.gif');background-size: 200 250; height: 200; width: 250;"></div>

  <div class="imageGallery" style="background-image:url('http://images.clipartpanda.com/teacher-apple-border-clipart-KTjgkqLTq.jpeg'); background-size: 200 250; height: 200; width: 250;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the events are removed, use event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click', ".imageGallery", function() {
```

---

```js
$('a.popup').popup();

$(document).on('click', ".imageGallery", function() {
    var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
    alert(bg);
});
```

```css
.imageGallery { width: 200px; height: 250px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://docs.toddish.co.uk/css/plugins/popup.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://docs.toddish.co.uk/js/plugins/jquery.popup.min.js"></script>

<div class="imageChoice" style="background-size: 200 250; height: 200; width: 250;"><a href=#gallery class="popup">Open gallery</a>
</div>

<div id="gallery" style="display:none">
  <div class="imageGallery" style="background-image:url('http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/apple_topic.png?w=600'); background-size: 200 250; height: 200; width: 250;"></div>

  <div class="imageGallery" style="background-image:url('http://images.clipartpanda.com/educational-clipart-M9TpyejiE.gif');background-size: 200 250; height: 200; width: 250;"></div>

  <div class="imageGallery" style="background-image:url('http://images.clipartpanda.com/teacher-apple-border-clipart-KTjgkqLTq.jpeg'); background-size: 200 250; height: 200; width: 250;"></div>
</div>
```